# How to sum up a repeating/chained formula in Google Sheets without typing each out?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I've got a chain of formulas I need that works out to:

```
=((C5*A5)+(C6*A6)+(C7*A7)+(C8*A8))/A3

=((D5*A5)+(D6*A6)+(D7*A7)+(D8*A8))/A3
```

All the way into 100's of rows, that I then need for subsequent columns. How do I make this cleaner and not have to type out every single (C*A)+etc.. I remember seeing a function at one point, but have failed to find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you want to go from **C5** all the way through **C100**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C5:C100)*(A5:A100))/A3
```

will work in both Excel and Google Sheets.